# Relative path issue in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I used the following code to access a file in my project. It worked great when the code file was located in the root folder. However, I've moved the file into the folder (**utils**) and now it's getting the wrong path.

`var filePath = path.join(__dirname, '/test/test.txt'`);

Currently I'm getting

```
 c://Users//i0433//WebstormProjects//Aps//utils//test//test.txt'
```

I need to remove **utils** so I can get the correct path.

```
c://Users//i0433//WebstormProjects//Aps//test//test.txt'
```

Comment: Usually in this instance adding a `..` to the beginning of the path will work: `var filePath = path.join(__dirname, '../test/test.txt');` although I'm not sure I completely understand your question.

Comment: @ChrisThompson- please provide it as answer :) \

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually in this instance adding a `..` to the beginning of the path will work:

```
var filePath = path.join(__dirname, '../test/test.txt');
```